# Kohana - Insert record with ignore duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, kohana

How to implement "insert ignore"? using kohana orm While adding multiple records, if few of them may already exist in database using below code adding of all 100 records will be declined.

```
$query = DB::insert('tablename', array('column1', 'column2','column3'));

 foreach ($data as $d) {
    $query->values($d);
 }
 try {
    $result = $query->execute();
 } catch ( Database_Exception $e ) {   
    echo $e->getMessage();
 }
```

**UPDATE:** 
Here is how i did This, i have to insert multiple records,

```
$Xtransactions = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `tablename` (`tid`, `tdate`, `appid`, 
                                              `userid`, `user_ip`) VALUES";

foreach ($objSas->trecord as $trow) {                      
  $Xtransactions .= "(".$trow->tid.",'". 
  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($trow->tdate))."',".
  $trow->userid.",".
  $trow->Xnumber.",'".
  $trow->ip."'),";
}
    $Xtransactions  = substr($Xtransactions , 0, -1);                         
 try {                      
      DB::query(Database::INSERT, $Xtransactions )->execute();
 } catch ( Database_Exception $e ) {   
      echo $e->getMessage();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

With query builder this is impossible, try to write a raw query.

```
DB::query(Database::INSERT, 'INSERT IGNORE INTO table VALUES (...)')->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually collect such modifications in static helper class, for example

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Helper_DB_Query{
/**
 * @param Database_Query_Builder_Insert $insert query thant need to be converted
 * @return Database_Query converted query
 */
    public static function insert_to_insert_ignore( Database_Query_Builder_Insert $insert ){

        $insert = (string) $insert;

        $query = preg_replace("/^INSERT(.*)$/", "INSERT IGNORE $1", $insert);

        return DB::query(Database::INSERT, $query);

    }



}
```